# Quotient homomorphisms of rings and point functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading the first page of this link http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/l_15.pdf.

This equality $$\left\{{h: R\to T: h \text{ homomorphism}} \right\} = \left\{{(a_1, ..., a_n): f_j (a_1, ..., a_n ) = 0, \forall {j}}\right\}$$ is what the paper means?

Thank you

Comment: "This equality ... is what the paper means?" is somewhat ambiguous, and you've given no affirmation to what the posted Answer supplies.  Perhaps you could refine the body of the Question and give more context to what you are asking?  The mention of *point functor* in the title has no clear referent in the body, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but indeed the claim in that PDF is correct, and it is what you described.

By the universal property of quotients, homomorphisms $R \to T$ are in bijective correspondence with homomorphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to T$ such that $\varphi(f_i) = 0$ for all $i$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is free on $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, homomorphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to T$ are in bijective correspondence with tuples $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in T^n$. Under this correspondence, the homomorphism determined by $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ sends $f$ to $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$.

So the set of homomorphisms $R \to T$ is therefore in bijective correspondence with the set of tuples $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ such that $f_i(a_1, \dots, a_n) = 0$ for all $i$, exactly as you described. This bijection is natural in $T$.

Comment: IF I INSERT a body instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, for example, $\mathbb{Q}$ DOES NOT AFFECT THE RESULT IN ANYTHING?

Comment: If you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$ in the above, you certainly end up with a different functor of points. For example, there are no ring homomorphisms whatsoever $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to \mathbb{Z}$, while of course there are many homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to \mathbb{Z}$. The difference is that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is free on $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ in the category of commutative rings (aka commutative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras), while $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is free in the category of commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras (not as a commutative ring!)